# Send Email Notification of Task to Queue Members

Tags: queue, task-notifications

I have recently set up a queue consisting of three associates.  All Associates have valid emails in the Salesforce.  I have tried a couple different settings, but nothing seems to work.  First, I included the queue email and marked the check box to "send email to members".  Then I removed the email address and left the check box marked.  I checked my email deliverability settings and they are set for "all email".  Regardless of what I do, all three users are not getting notified when a task is assigned to the queue.  How can I get the email notification to be sent to all three members when a task is assigned to the queue?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE. What type of queue do you have? Is the queue for a specif object other than Tasks? If so, that could be the problem. Is the queue assigned to members of a group? Is the Task related to a record owned by the queue? More details of this kind would be helpful.

Comment: The queue is assigned only to the Task object.  The members are three individual users.  The task assigned is usually tied to a record owned by a different user (not one of the tree in the queue).

Comment: Is sharing on the parent record Public or Private? If the queue members don't have at least read permission on the parent record, that could explain why this is happening. Check to make certain the parent record for the Task is being shared with the queue members.

Comment: Yes, all of the members have access to the parent record.

Comment: We had the same problem - Please upvote this idea: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdkiWUAR/task-queue-notificationstrigger-queue-notification-email-for-new-queue-records. Thanks, Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been having the same problem.

I noticed something at this help page: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=task_considerations.htm&type=5

> Emails, notifications, and reminders are only sent after tasks are reassigned from the queue to a specific user.

We have setup a process builder with an email alert as a temporary solution.

Comment: I disagree with the above delete vote. It'd be nice to hear a bit more detail, but a workaround is presented here.

Comment: I have not set up an email alert before.  Could you provide some direction on how to do this?  Would it still include the direct link for the task?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get an email alert to go out using a workflow rule triggered off of the task ownerid.  When the ID changed to the queue, and email alert goes to all of the members of the queue.